# ¿Cómo cambiar el formato del arreglo dependiendo del texto de la llave?

Tags: php, array, string

Necesito cambiar el formato del arreglo

Tengo

```
[
    "direccion.no" => ["text1", "text2"],
    "direccion.calle" => ["text1", "text2"],
]
```

Quiero tener el resultado

```
[
    "direccion." => [
        "no" => ["text1", "text2"],
        "calle" => ["text1", "text2"]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: if (str_contains($propertyPath, '.'))
                $column = explode('.', $propertyPath);

pero solo obtengo como valor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo hay que recorrer el array, y hacerle `explode()` al key (indice) inicial.
La primera parte corresponderá al índice del 1er nivel, y la segunda al segundo nivel. Cambié `str_contains()` por `strpos()`, porque si un índice empieza en `.`, se rompería todo.

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array_de_muestra as $k=>$v) {
    if(strpos($k, '.') > 0) {
        list($key1, $key2) = explode('.', $k);
        $new_array[$key1][$key2] = $v;
    }
}
```

Usando el array de referencia, se obtiene:

```
var_dump($new_array);
/* Resultado: 
array(
    "direccion" => array (
        "no" => array (text1, text2),
        "calle" => array(text1, text2)
    )
)*/
```